# filter by foreign key in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I have following models:

```
class VKLink(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class BaseComment(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(VKLink)
    from_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=3000)

    def is_own(self):
        return self.from_id == self.owner.user_id
```

BaseComment is counted as 'own comment' if from_id equals to links user_id.
I want to get all BaseComments that are 'own'.
How can I select it in django models term?

`BaseComment.objects.filter(from_id=owner__user_id)` does not work, as `owner__user_id` is not defined at that stage.

Comment: You *might* need to use `extra()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`F()` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters):

```
BaseComment.objects.filter(from_id=F('owner__user_id'))
```